# Effects of cancelling an alarm manager in android

Tags: android

In my android app, I have an alarm manager that runs at sunset each day at intervals of 30mins. In my broadcast receiver, I have code to check the current time and compare it to sunrise. Once the current time is greater than sunrise I cancel the alarm manager, passing in the particular pending intent. What I would like to know is once the sunrise time is reached and the alarm is cancelled, does this mean that the alarm has to be restarted for it run again the next day at sunset or will it just automatically run again? Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am getting right this is what you are trying:

> - After sunset,Alarm will ring
> - Will keep on ringing after every 30 mins
> - At the time of sunrise,Alarm should go off.

If this is what you are saying,then `yes`.You have to create an object of `alaram Manager` everytime at sunset through a `pending intent` and need to `cancel` that alaram every day by passing the same `pendingIntent` on the next sunrise of the day

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying. I have created an alarm manager object and gave it a pending intent and I have checked that it starts and stops at the correct times the first time. But i want to know when it is stopped will this same alarm manager run at the next sunset?

Comment: if by **stopped** you mean **cancel** then **yes** is the answer

Comment: Yes sorry, i meant cancelled. Thanks!